# undeclared variable in testing strategy

Tags: pine-script

[image]Im trying to add this indicator to my test but i have encounter a error, i am familiar with with python but in pinescript i dont get why e1 variable is being use as e1 and the e1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPD3.png) in the same line and according to the web there is no way for me to use a console to even see what value e1 holds

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © quechon
//@version=4
strategy('Testing indicators', process_orders_on_close=true)

//time to backtest from
start = timestamp(2017, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2020, 11, 03, 0, 0, 0)

var float e1 = 0

//fxSniper
CCI_Period = 14
T3_Period = 3 //default is 5
b = 0.618
xPrice = close
b2 = b*b
b3 = b2*b
c1 = -b3
c2 = (3*(b2 + b3))
c3 = -3*(2*b2 + b + b3)
c4 = (1 + 3*b + b3 + 3*b2)
nn = iff(T3_Period < 1, 1, T3_Period)
nr = 1 + 0.5*(nn - 1)
w1 = 2 / (nr + 1)
w2 = 1 - w1    
xcci = cci(xPrice, CCI_Period)
e1 = w1*xcci + w2*nz(e1[1])
e2 = w1*e1 + w2*nz(e2[1])
e3 = w1*e2 + w2*nz(e3[1])
e4 = w1*e3 + w2*nz(e4[1])
e5 = w1*e4 + w2*nz(e5[1])
e6 = w1*e5 + w2*nz(e6[1])
xccir = c1*e6 + c2*e5 + c3*e4 + c4*e3  

//buy long when price crosses above dpo
long = xccir > 0
    
// short when price is below dpo
short = xccir < 0

if time >= start and time <= end
    
    
    //strategy to buy according to dpo
    if long
        strategy.close('Short')
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, 10000)
        
    //strategy to go short
    if short
        strategy.close('Long')
        strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, 10000)
```

im getting this error cannot figure out how to fix it

```
Add to chart operation failed. reason: line 27: Undeclared identifier 'e1'
```

Have done some searching but cant figure it out

original script

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Copyright by HPotter v1.0 25/07/2014
// This simple indicator gives you a lot of useful information - when to enter, when to exit
// and how to reduce risks by entering a trade on a double confirmed signal.
// You can use in the xPrice any series: Open, High, Low, Close, HL2, HLC3, OHLC4 and ect...
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
study(title="FX Sniper:  T3-CCI", shorttitle="T3-CCI")
CCI_Period = input(14, minval=1)
T3_Period = input(5, minval=1)
b = input(0.618)
hline(0, color=purple, linestyle=line)
xPrice = close
plot(xPrice)
b2 = b*b
b3 = b2*b
c1 = -b3
c2 = (3*(b2 + b3))
c3 = -3*(2*b2 + b + b3)
c4 = (1 + 3*b + b3 + 3*b2)
nn = iff(T3_Period < 1, 1, T3_Period)
nr = 1 + 0.5*(nn - 1)
w1 = 2 / (nr + 1)
w2 = 1 - w1    
xcci = cci(xPrice, CCI_Period)
e1 = w1*xcci + w2*nz(e1[1])
e2 = w1*e1 + w2*nz(e2[1])
e3 = w1*e2 + w2*nz(e3[1])
e4 = w1*e3 + w2*nz(e4[1])
e5 = w1*e4 + w2*nz(e5[1])
e6 = w1*e5 + w2*nz(e6[1])
xccir = c1*e6 + c2*e5 + c3*e4 + c4*e3  
cciHcolor = iff(xccir >= 0 , green,
        iff(xccir < 0, red, black))
plot(xccir, color=blue, title="T3-CCI")
plot(xccir, color=cciHcolor, title="CCIH", style = histogram)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Expressions, declarations and statements](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html)

You're declaring a mutable variable `e1`, so you must use `:=` to assign a value to it.
You should also declare variables `e2` to `e6` as mutable variables, because you're referencing their previous value by using `e2[1]`.
Since you didn't explicitly declare `e2`, it's declared on first use.
At the same time, you're trying to reference it's history, which doesn't exist yet at that point.

This will work.
I've also modified some code to make use of existing functions and converted some variables to input, so you can change them in the settings of your indicator, without needing to change the source code.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © quechon
//@version=4
strategy('Testing indicators', process_orders_on_close=true)

//time to backtest from
start = timestamp(2017, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2020, 11, 03, 0, 0, 0)

var float e1 = 0
var float e2 = 0
var float e3 = 0
var float e4 = 0
var float e5 = 0
var float e6 = 0

//fxSniper
var int CCI_Period = input(14, "CCI_Period", minval=0)
var int T3_Period = input(3, "T3_Period", minval=0) //default is 5
b = 0.618
xPrice = input(close, "xPrice", type=input.source)
b2 = pow(b,2)
b3 = pow(b,3)
c1 = -b3
c2 = (3*(b2 + b3))
c3 = -3*(2*b2 + b + b3)
c4 = (1 + 3*b + b3 + 3*b2)
nn = T3_Period < 1 ? 1 : T3_Period
nr = 1 + 0.5*(nn - 1)
w1 = 2 / (nr + 1)
w2 = 1 - w1    
xcci = cci(xPrice, CCI_Period)
e1 := w1*xcci + w2*nz(e1[1])
e2 := w1*e1 + w2*nz(e2[1])
e3 := w1*e2 + w2*nz(e3[1])
e4 := w1*e3 + w2*nz(e4[1])
e5 := w1*e4 + w2*nz(e5[1])
e6 := w1*e5 + w2*nz(e6[1])
xccir = c1*e6 + c2*e5 + c3*e4 + c4*e3  

//buy long when price crosses above dpo
long = crossover(xccir, 0) 
    
// short when price is below dpo
short = crossunder(xccir, 0)

if time >= start and time <= end
    //strategy to buy according to dpo
    if long
        strategy.close('Short')
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, 10000)
        
    //strategy to go short
    if short
        strategy.close('Long')
        strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, 10000)
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the help but for some reason if i plot the xccir variable it will be off by a day the original script plots a line all the way to last candle this script plot one untill the day before any idea why and again thanks for the help

Comment: The original script doesn't even compile. Because of that, I'm wondering how can you see it plotting all the way to the last candle? Can you provide a script + screenshot that shows this please? Maybe that'll clear things up.

Comment: pasted original script is the last piece of code thanks

Comment: added a screenshot and after playing around with the script discovered that the strategy function is the problem as soon i replace it with study script works like original one so gotta figure out whats is going on there